# Python out of memory on large CSV file (numpy)

Tags: python, memory, csv, numpy, scipy

I have a 3GB CSV file that I try to read with python, I need the median column wise.

```
from numpy import * 
def data():
    return genfromtxt('All.csv',delimiter=',')

data = data() # This is where it fails already.

med = zeros(len(data[0]))
data = data.T
for i in xrange(len(data)):
    m = median(data[i])
    med[i] = 1.0/float(m)
print med
```

The error that I get is this:

```
Python(1545) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)

*** error: can't allocate region

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Normalize.py", line 40, in <module>

  data = data()

  File "Normalize.py", line 39, in data

  return genfromtxt('All.csv',delimiter=',')

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-
packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1495, in genfromtxt

for (i, line) in enumerate(itertools.chain([first_line, ], fhd)):

MemoryError
```

I think it's just an out of memory error. I am running a 64bit MacOSX with 4GB of ram and both numpy and Python compiled in 64bit mode.

How do I fix this? Should I try a distributed approach, just for the memory management?

Thanks

EDIT: Also tried with this but no luck...

```
genfromtxt('All.csv',delimiter=',', dtype=float16)
```

Comment: Use [pandas.read_csv](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=543) it's significantly faster.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As other folks have mentioned, for a really large file, you're better off iterating.

However, you do commonly want the entire thing in memory for various reasons.

`genfromtxt` is much less efficient than `loadtxt` (though it handles missing data, whereas `loadtxt` is more "lean and mean", which is why the two functions co-exist).

If your data is very regular (e.g. just simple delimited rows of all the same type), you can also improve on either by using `numpy.fromiter`.

If you have enough ram, consider using `np.loadtxt('yourfile.txt', delimiter=',')` (You may also need to specify `skiprows` if you have a header on the file.)

As a quick comparison, loading ~500MB text file with `loadtxt` uses ~900MB of ram at peak usage, while loading the same file with `genfromtxt` uses ~2.5GB.

**Loadtxt**
[image: Memory and CPU usage of numpy.loadtxt while loading a ~500MB ascii file]

---

**Genfromtxt**
[image: Memory and CPU usage of numpy.genfromtxt while loading a ~500MB ascii file]

---

Alternately, consider something like the following.  It will only work for very simple, regular data, but it's quite fast. (`loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` do a lot of guessing and error-checking. If your data is very simple and regular, you can improve on them greatly.)

```
import numpy as np

def generate_text_file(length=1e6, ncols=20):
    data = np.random.random((length, ncols))
    np.savetxt('large_text_file.csv', data, delimiter=',')

def iter_loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', skiprows=0, dtype=float):
    def iter_func():
        with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
            for _ in range(skiprows):
                next(infile)
            for line in infile:
                line = line.rstrip().split(delimiter)
                for item in line:
                    yield dtype(item)
        iter_loadtxt.rowlength = len(line)

    data = np.fromiter(iter_func(), dtype=dtype)
    data = data.reshape((-1, iter_loadtxt.rowlength))
    return data

#generate_text_file()
data = iter_loadtxt('large_text_file.csv')
```

**Fromiter**

[image: Using fromiter to load the same ~500MB data file]

Comment: Basically, brute force. :)  Here's my shell script, if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/2447356  It's far from elegant, but it's close enough.

Comment: Ah, nice! (Although I'll admit I was hoping for `import memoryprofile` or something, drat!)

Comment: Well, there's `heapy`, (part of guppy: http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/ ) but it doesn't work well for numpy arrays, unfortunately.  Shame, though, `import memoryprofile` would be damned nice!

Comment: dear @JoeKington, can you please use a single scale for the Y axes of your graphs, so that the comparison is visually similar?

Comment: IMO, you should better compare  memory usage  with output array size instead of file size. For example if you want to load a 8192x8192 double precision matrix, then an optimal function would only need  512MB (8 * 8192 * 8192 bytes) to load it, regardless how large is the text file.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with using genfromtxt() is that it attempts to load the whole file into memory, i.e. into a numpy array. This is great for small files but BAD for 3GB inputs like yours. Since you are just calculating column medians, there's no need to read the whole file. A simple, but not the most efficient way to do it would be to read the whole file line-by-line multiple times and iterate over the columns.

Comment: Well, okay. But is there a more sustainable solution to this? Like in a java program, you can choose to start it up with, say, 5GB of memory. Is there an equivalent for Python? I mean, next time I might just have a CSV file with a single line of 4Gb..

Comment: Python doesn't limit how much memory you can allocate. If you get `MemoryError` in 64-bit Python, you really are out of memory.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all of the Python modules support 64-bit architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you not using the python [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module?

```
>> import csv
>> reader = csv.reader(open('All.csv'))
>>> for row in reader:
...     print row
```

Comment: Because my whole program uses numpy and basic linear algebra.. with the reader I can't do all that stuff.

Comment: Combined with the answer of kz26 this actually gives a workable workaround. Also funny: After one iteration the file is cached and the process jumps from 60 to 99% cpu.