# NumPy reading file with filtering lines on the fly

Tags: python, input, numpy, large-files, bigdata

I have a large array of numbers written in a CSV file and need to load only a slice of that array. Conceptually I want to call `np.genfromtxt()` and then row-slice the resulting array, but

1. the file is so large that may not to fit in RAM
2. the number of relevant rows might be small, so there is no need to parse every line.

MATLAB has the function `textscan()` that can take a file descriptor and read only a chunk of the file. Is there anything like that in NumPy?

For now, I defined the following function that reads only the lines that satisfy the given condition:

```
def genfromtxt_cond(fname, cond=(lambda str: True)):
  res = []
  with open(fname) as file:
    for line in file:
      if cond(line):
        res.append([float(s) for s in line.split()])

  return np.array(res, dtype=np.float64)
```

There are several problems with this solution:

- not general: supports only the float type, while `genfromtxt` detects the types, which may vary from column to column; also missing values, converters, skipping, etc.;
- not efficient: when the condition is difficult, every line may be parsed twice, also the used data structure and reading bufferization may be suboptimal;
- requires writing code.

Is there a standard function that implements filtering, or some counterpart of MATLAB’s `textscan`?

Comment: Why not just ``yield line``  or ``yield line.split()`` instead of building ``res`` then it's agnostic on the data in ``line``.

Comment: @sotapme How is it helpful? Do you mean generator is faster than `append`? I need the filtered np.array() in the end, anyway

Comment: You said that yours only supported ``float`` so as you'd already generalised ``cond`` I thought yielding the line would allow you to use the same ``genfromtxt_cond`` irrespective of the line data.  I was thinking of code reuse and not performance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can think of two approaches that provide some of the functionality you are asking for:

1. **To read a file either in chunks / or in strides of n-lines / etc.:**
   You can pass a `generator` to [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) as well as to [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt). This way you can load a large dataset from a textfile memory-efficiently while retaining **all** the convenient parsing features of the two functions.
2. **To read data only from lines that match a criterion that can be expressed as a regex:**
   You can use [numpy.fromregex](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html#numpy.fromregex) and  use a `regular expression` to **precisely** define which tokens from a given line in the input file should be loaded. Lines not matching the pattern will be ignored.

To illustrate the two approaches, I'm going to use an example from my research context.
I often need to load files with the following structure:

```
6
 generated by VMD
  CM         5.420501        3.880814        6.988216
  HM1        5.645992        2.839786        7.044024
  HM2        5.707437        4.336298        7.926170
  HM3        4.279596        4.059821        7.029471
  OD1        3.587806        6.069084        8.018103
  OD2        4.504519        4.977242        9.709150
6
 generated by VMD
  CM         5.421396        3.878586        6.989128
  HM1        5.639769        2.841884        7.045364
  HM2        5.707584        4.343513        7.928119
  HM3        4.277448        4.057222        7.022429
  OD1        3.588119        6.069086        8.017814
```

These files can be huge (GBs) and I'm only interested in the numerical data. All data blocks have the same size -- `6` in this example -- and they are always separated by two lines. So the `stride` of the blocks is `8`.

### Using the first approach:

First I'm going to define a generator that filters out the undesired lines:

```
def filter_lines(f, stride):
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i%stride and (i-1)%stride:
            yield line
```

Then I open the file, create a `filter_lines`-generator (here I need to know the `stride`), and pass that generator to `genfromtxt`:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    data = np.genfromtxt(filter_lines(f, 8),
                         dtype='f',
                         usecols=(1, 2, 3))
```

This works like a breeze. Note that I'm able to use `usecols` to get rid of the first column of the data. In the same way, you could use all the other features of `genfromtxt` -- detecting the types, varying types from column to column, missing values, converters, etc.

In this example `data.shape` was `(204000, 3)` while the original file consisted of `272000` lines.

Here the `generator` is used to filter homogenously strided lines but one can likewise imagine it filtering out inhomogenous blocks of lines based on (simple) criteria.

### Using the second approach:

Here's the `regexp` I'm going to use:

```
regexp = r'\s+\w+' + r'\s+([-.0-9]+)' * 3 + r'\s*\n'
```

Groups -- i.e. inside `()` -- define the tokens to be extracted from a given line.
Next, `fromregex` does the job and ignores lines not matching the pattern:

```
data = np.fromregex(fname, regexp, dtype='f')
```

The result is exactly the same as in the first approach.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks. So if I understand correctly, the main benefit of using the generator instead of the direct file path is that we save space storing the data. I'm assuming it's unavoidable reading in the data since that's the only way we can know if we want to filter it out or not. Will this speed loading files up significantly? Or will it actually be slower since we need to first filter and then pass that iterable to genfromtxt?

Comment: I understand this answer is back from 2013, so I am not sure if things have changed. At this moment I can't find anything about generators in the documentation. Best guess: converters, but they seem to provided a limited functionality compared to this answer's. Does this still work? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a list of types (the format condition), use a try block and use yield to use genfromtxt as a generator, we should be able to replicate `textscan()`.

```
def genfromtext(fname, formatTypes):
    with open(fname, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            try:
                line = line.split(',')  # Do you care about line anymore?
                r = []
                for type, cell in zip(formatTypes, line):
                    r.append(type(cell))
            except:
                pass  # Fail silently on this line since we hit an error
            yield r
```

Edit: I forgot the except block. It runs okay now and you can use genfromtext as a generator like so (using a random CSV log I have sitting around):

```
>>> a = genfromtext('log.txt', [str, str, str, int])
>>> a.next()
['10.10.9.45', ' 2013/01/17 16:29:26', '00:00:36', 0]
>>> a.next()
['10.10.9.45', ' 2013/01/17 16:22:20', '00:08:14', 0]
>>> a.next()
['10.10.9.45', ' 2013/01/17 16:31:05', '00:00:11', 3]
```

I should probably note that I'm using `zip` to zip together the comma split line and the formatSpec which will tuplify the two lists (stopping when one of the lists runs out of items) so we can iterate over them together, avoiding a loop dependent on `len(line)` or something like that.

Comment: You answer is relevant, but what I really wanted is to solve my problem with available library functions as efficient and powerful as genfromtxt. A custom implementation — either filtering version (in Q) or `textscan` version (in your A) — suffer from several problems I listed above.

Comment: What optimisations does textscan offer above this besides being a standard function? It's relatively simple to add a block to skip leading lines and yield only N lines from the file, conversion bails out of a line as soon as reasonably possible (you could even remove conversion and return the original string to save on `append`s), and the whole thing is extremely lazy so memory use is minimal. You could potentially use linecache to improve access speed at the cost of memory usage but I can't comment much on its use.

Comment: I accept your answer, since you answered the question, indeed. Although I wanted to know if there is a library implementation, where one does not need to implement all the features `np.genfromtxt` has. Most likely, there is not one, so your answer is the best fit.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to demonstrate comment to OP.

```
def fread(name, cond):
    with open(name) as file:
        for line in file:
            if cond(line):
                yield line.split()

def a_genfromtxt_cond(fname, cond=(lambda str: True)):
    """Seems to work without need to convert to float."""
    return np.array(list(fread(fname, cond)), dtype=np.float64)

def b_genfromtxt_cond(fname, cond=(lambda str: True)):
    r = [[int(float(i)) for i in l] for l in fread(fname, cond)]
    return np.array(r, dtype=np.integer)


a = a_genfromtxt_cond("tar.data")
print a
aa = b_genfromtxt_cond("tar.data")
print aa
```

Output

```
[[ 1.   2.3  4.5]
 [ 4.7  9.2  6.7]
 [ 4.7  1.8  4.3]]
[[1 2 4]
 [4 9 6]
 [4 1 4]]
```

Comment: Also see `numpy.fromiter` if you're worried about reducing memory usage (i.e. no intermediate list).  It's for 1D arrays, but you can make it work with 2D without too much trouble.  Not to plug my own answer, but see the last example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8964779/325565