# Python quick data read-in and slice

Tags: python, arrays, optimization

I've got the following code in python and I think I'd need some help optimizing it.
I'm reading in a few million lines of data, but then throwing out most of them if one coordinate per line is not fitting my criterion.
The code is as following:

```
def loadFargoData(dataname, thlimit):
    temp = np.loadtxt(dataname)
    return temp[ np.abs(temp[:,1]) < thlimit ]
```

I've coded it as if it were C-type code and of course in python now this is crazy slow.
Can I throw out my temp object somehow? Or what other optimization can the Pythonian population help me with?

Comment: May be a duplicete of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645789/numpy-reading-file-with-filtering-lines-on-the-fly

Comment: @Zefick: Thanks for the link. Indeed that would solve my problem, if it is possible to construct regular expressions that mimick mathematical operations like \ge... Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data reader included in pandas might speed up your script.  It reads faster than numpy.  Pandas will produce a dataframe object, easy to view as a numpy array (also easy to convert if preferred) so you can execute your condition in numpy (which looks efficient enough in your question).

```
import pandas as pd

def loadFargoData(dataname, thlimit):
    temp = pd.read_csv(dataname)  # returns a dataframe
    temp = temp.values            # returns a numpy array
    # the 2 lines above can be replaced by   temp = pd.read_csv(dataname).values
    return temp[ np.abs(temp[:,1]) < thlimit ]
```

You might want to check up Pandas' documentation to learn the function arguments you may need to read the file correctly (header, separator, etc).

Comment: Sorry for the late accepting of your answer, I was busy with another project. The Pandas reader in fact works wonderful, I get a speed-up by a factor of 15-16 for my data.