# Suggestions for faster for/if statements in my code?

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, for-loop, numpy

My code takes about two hours to process. The bottleneck is in for loop and if
statements (see comment in code).
I'm beginner with python :) Can anyone recommend an efficient python way to replace the nested for and if statements?

I have tables of ~30 million rows, each row with (x,y,z) values:

> 20.0  11.3   7
>   21.0  11.3   0
>   22.0  11.3   3
>   ...

My desired output is a table in the form x, y, min(z), count(min(z)). The last
column is a final count of the least z values at that (x,y). Eg:

> 20.0  11.3   7  7
>   21.0  11.3   0  10
>   22.0  11.3   3  1
>   ...

There's only about 600 unique coordinates, so the output table will be 600x4.
My code:

```
import numpy as np
file = open('input.txt','r');

coordset = set()
data = np.zeros((600,4))*np.nan
irow = 0 
ctr = 0 

for row in file:
    item = row.split()
    x = float(item[0])
    y = float(item[1])
    z = float(item[2])

    # build unique grid of coords
    if ((x,y)) not in coordset:
        data[irow][0] = x 
        data[irow][1] = y 
        data[irow][2] = z 
        irow = irow + 1     # grows up to 599 

    # lookup table of unique coords
    coordset.add((x,y))

    # BOTTLENECK. replace ifs? for?
    for i in range(0, irow):
        if data[i][0]==x and data[i][1]==y:
            if z > data[i][2]:
                continue
            elif z==data[i][2]:
                ctr = ctr + 1
                data[i][3]=ctr
            if z < data[i][2]:
                data[i][2] = z
                ctr = 1
                data[i][3]=ctr
```

**edit:** For reference the approach by @Joowani computes in 1m26s. My original approach, same computer, same datafile, 106m23s.
**edit2:** @Ophion and @Sibster thanks for suggestions, I don't have enough credit to +1 useful answers.

Comment: is 30million rows really great to save in txt? shouldnt you look at some more sophisticated format to save (and read in) your data? Also i suggest vectorization (numpy) whenever possible since that pushes the for-loops into numpy, which is C (hence faster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems slow because it iterates through the list (i.e. data) *every* time you make an update. A better approach would be using a dictionary, which takes O(1) as opposed to O(n) per update.

Here would be my solution using a dictionary:

```
file = open('input.txt', 'r')

#coordinates
c = {}

for line in file:
    #items
    (x, y, z) = (float(n) for n in line.split())

    if (x, y) not in c:
        c[(x, y)] = [z, 1]
    elif c[(x, y)][0] > z:
        c[(x, y)][0], c[(x, y)][1] = z, 1
    elif c[(x, y)][0] == z:
        c[(x, y)][1] += 1

for key in c:
    print("{} {} {} {}".format(key[0], key[1], c[key][0], c[key][1]))
```

Comment: To add some, I found a reference (http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) that explains some the efficiency in dictionary operations.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the last if to an elif ?

Like it is done now you will evaluate the `z < data[i][2]:` every iteration of the loop.

You could even just replace it with an else since you have already checked `if z>data[i][2]` and `z == data[i][2]` so the only remaining possibility is `z < data[i][2]:`

So following code will do the same and should be faster :

```
        if z > data[i][2]:
            continue
        elif z==data[i][2]:
            ctr = ctr + 1
            data[i][3]=ctr
        else:
            data[i][2] = z
            ctr = 1
            data[i][3]=ctr
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this in numpy use `np.unique`.

```
def count_unique(arr):
    row_view=np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void,a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1])))
    ua, uind = np.unique(row_view,return_inverse=True)
    unique_rows = ua.view(a.dtype).reshape(ua.shape + (-1,))
    count=np.bincount(uind)
    return np.hstack((unique_rows,count[:,None]))
```

First lets check for a small array:

```
a=np.random.rand(10,3)
a=np.around(a,0)

print a
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 print output
[[ 0.  0.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  2.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.]]

 print np.sum(output[:,-1])
 10
```

Looks good! Now lets check for a large array:

```
a=np.random.rand(3E7,3)
a=np.around(a,1)

output=count_unique(a)
print output.shape
(1331, 4)  #Close as I can get to 600 unique elements.

print np.sum(output[:,-1])
30000000.0
```

Takes about 33 second on my machine and 3GB of memory, doing this all in memory for large arrays will likely be your bottleneck. For a reference @Joowani's solution took about 130 seconds, although this is a bit of an apple and oranges comparison as we start with a numpy array. Your milage may vary.

To read in the data as a numpy array I would view the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259393/), but it should look something like the following:

```
arr=np.genfromtxt("./input.txt", delimiter=" ")
```

Loading in that much data from a txt file I would really recommend using the `pandas` example in that link.