# Using find_peaks in loop to find peak heights from data

Tags: python, numpy

This problem is about using `scipy.signal.find_peaks` for extracting mean peak height from data files efficiently. I am a beginner with Python (3.7), so I am not sure if I have written my code in the most optimal way, with regard to speed and code quality.

I have a set of measurement files containing one million data points (30MB) each. The graph of this data is a signal with peaks at regular intervals, and with noise. Also, the baseline and the amplitude of the signal vary across parts of the signal. I attached an image of an example. The signal can be much less clean.

[image: this is what the peaks might look like]

My goal is to calculate the mean height of the peaks for each file. In order to do this, first I use `find_peaks` to locate all the peaks. Then, I loop over each peak location and detect the peak in a small interval around the peak, to make sure I get the local height of the peak.

I then put all these heights in numpy arrays and calculate their mean and standard deviation afterwards.

Here is a barebone version of my code, it is a bit long but I think that might also be because I am doing something wrong.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

# Allocate empty lists for values
mean_heights = []
std_heights = []
mean_baselines = []
std_baselines = []
temperatures = []

# Loop over several files, read them in and process data
for file in file_list:
    temperatures.append(file)
    # Load in data from a file of 30 MB
    t_dat, x_dat = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
    # Find all peaks in this file
    peaks, peak_properties = find_peaks(x_dat, prominence=prom, width=0)

    # Calculate window size, make sure it is even
    if round(len(t_dat)/len(peaks)) % 2 == 0:
        n_points = len(t_dat) // len(peaks)
    else:
        n_points = len(t_dat) // len(peaks) + 1

    t_slice = t_dat[-1] / len(t_dat)

    # Allocate np arrays for storing heights
    baseline_list = np.zeros(len(peaks) - 2)
    height_list = np.zeros(len(peaks) - 2)

    # Loop over all found peaks, and re-detect the peak in a window around the peak to be able
    # to detect its local height without triggering to a baseline far away
    for i in range(len(peaks) - 2):
        # Making a window around a peak_properties
        sub_t = t_dat[peaks[i+1] - n_points // 2: peaks[i+1] + n_points // 2]
        sub_x = x_dat[peaks[i+1] - n_points // 2: peaks[i+1] + n_points // 2]
        # Detect the peaks (2 version, specific to the application I have)
        h_min = max(sub_x) - np.mean(sub_x)
        _, baseline_props = find_peaks(
            sub_x, prominence=h_min, distance=n_points - 1, width=0)
        _, height_props = find_peaks(np.append(
            min(sub_x) - 1, sub_x), prominence=h_min, distance=n_points - 1, width=0)
        # Add the heights to the np arrays storing the heights
        baseline_list[i] = baseline_props["prominences"]
        height_list[i] = height_props["prominences"]

    # Fill lists with values, taking the stdev and mean of the np arrays with the heights
    mean_heights.append(np.mean(height_list))
    std_heights.append(np.std(height_list))
    mean_baselines.append(np.mean(baseline_list))
    std_baselines.append(np.std(baseline_list))
```

It takes ~30 s to execute. Is this normal or too slow? If so, can it be optimised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I have improved the speed by getting rid of various inefficiencies, that I found by using the Python profiler. I will list the optimisations here ordered by significance for the speed:

- Using pandas `pd.read_csv()` for I/O instead of `np.loadtxt()` cut off about 90% of the runtime. As also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259393/numpy-loading-csv-too-slow-compared-to-matlab), this saves a lot of time. This means changing this:

  ```py
  t_dat, x_dat = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
  ```

  to this:

  ```py
  data = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = "\t", names=["t_dat", "x_dat"])
  t_dat = data.values[:,0]
  x_dat = data.values[:,1]
  ```

- Removing redundant len() calls. I noticed that len() was called many times, and then noticed that this happened unnecessary. Changing this:

  ```py
  if round(len(t_dat) / len(peaks)) % 2 == 0:
      n_points = int(len(t_dat) / len(peaks))
  else:
      n_points = int(len(t_dat) / len(peaks) + 1)
  ```

  to this:

  ```py
  n_points = round(len(t_dat) / len(peaks))
  if n_points % 2 != 0:
      n_points += 1
  ```

proved to be also a significant improvement.

- Lastly, a disproportionally component of the computational time (about 20%) was used by the built in Python functions min(), max() and sum(). Since I was using numpy arrays already, switching to the numpy equivalents for these functions, resulted in a 84% improvement on this part. This means for example changing `max(sub_x)` to `sub_x.max()`.

These are all unrelated optimisations that I still think might be useful for Python beginner like myself, and they do help a lot.