# numpy array memory larger than expected

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I have a file bad_orders.csv approximately 16GB to be read into a numpy array within a 58GB RAM machine.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-232:~/Data/Autoencoder_Signin/joined_signin_rel$ free -g
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             58           0          58           0           0          58
Swap:             0           0           0
```

When I run the following command, the job has been killed repeatedly:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.genfromtxt('bad_orders.csv', delimiter =',', missing_values='',dtype='float32')
```

The terminal shows that it is using disproportionate memory:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-232:~$ free -g
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             58          42          12           0           3          16
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Then I tried to sample 10000 rows from the original file and check the memory usage:

```
In [7]: samples = np.genfromtxt('samples.csv',delimiter=',', 
missing_values='', dtype='float32')

In [8]: samples.nbytes
Out[8]: 16680000
```

The sample numpy array shows size of 0.017GB. My file in total has ~8M rows, so if the memory usage scales linearly the large numpy array should take 13GB memory. Why is it taking more than 50GB when I was reading the whole file?

Comment: Usage while loading the file will be more than the final array usage.  How many columns?  2085? (8 bytes per item, 1000 rows).  What's the typical line width?

Comment: Try a iterator/generator with `np.fromiter`. Might be slower, but should be much more memory efficient. And it shouldn't be too bad if you know the size beforehand. Something like `(map(float, row) for row in csv.reader(open('myfile.csv'))`

Comment: With pure floats, no missing values, and a simple delimiter, `genfromtxt` is probably overkill.  It's more useful when you need to use header field names, and automatically deduced field dtypes.

Comment: @hpaulj The total number of columns is 417. The reason why I used `genfromtxt` is that `loadtxt` cannot handle missing values, in which case my missing value is empty string.

Comment: Please let us know what happens, did you try pandas?

Comment: @anishtain4 Yep. Pandas seems like having the same problem...Memory usage exceeds the data size itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `genfromtxt` has a lot of type checking and is only intended for small files. For larger files you're better off with `loadtxt`, though still uses much more memory than the file as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956832/python-out-of-memory-on-large-csv-file-numpy).
Yet another better way is to use pandas' `read_csv`.

Comment: I thought both `genfromtxt` and `loadtxt` collect the data in a list of lists, one sublist per line of the `csv` file.  `genfromtxt` may do more checking, but I don't think that will change the memory usage.  But I haven't examined the code of both with that in mind.

Comment: @hpaulj Check the link I've provided. They have done speed tests as well as explaining why it's slower. Pandas is faster according to this link: http://akuederle.com/stop-using-numpy-loadtxt. I haven't done memory profiling on it, but I think since it's intended for big data, should be much more memory efficient as well.

Comment: The `pandas` one has two modes, the faster compiled, and slower Python version with more features.

Comment: The main difference seems to be that `loadtxt` loads the file in 50,000 line chunks, and converts the strings with a specified `dtype`.  `genfromtxt` splits all lines, and does the `dtype` conversion once, possibly using a dtype that it has deduced.